# Raster polygonization and number of classes

Tags: qgis

I created 4 height classes on a raster:

```
 ( "diff_2019-2016@1"   <= 0) *0 +  
("diff_2019-2016@1" > 0 AND  "diff_2019-2016@1" <= 0.5) *0.5 + 
( "diff_2019-2016@1" > 0.5 AND  "diff_2019-2016@1" <= 1) *1  +
( "diff_2019-2016@1" > 1) *2
```

When I polygonize this raster, I'm left with three classes (class 0-0.5 and 0.5-1 merge).

I don't understand my mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the classes have been assigned to an integer field, so the values are rounded and are therefore aggregated.

Comment: @`L'HGJ How do I assign values to a decimal field?

Comment: I don't know which tool you have used :) Otherwise assign integer values to the classes

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would work with the 'data_type' parameter but I can't pass it in the raster to vector polygon window.  So I'm open to ideas

Comment: @fcka then assign integer values to the classes

Comment: @ JGH That's exactly it. It works. THANKS !
example:                                                           ( "diff_2024-2016@1" <= 0) *0 + 
("diff_2024-2016@1" > 0 AND "diff_2024-2016@1" <= 0.5) *1+ 
( "diff_2024-2016@1" > 0.5 AND "diff_2024-2016@1" <= 1) *2 +
( "diff_2024-2016@1" > 1) *3